# unmet depedancies while installing package dovecot

Tags: server, apt, mysql, email, postfix

While I am trying to install the below package:
I am following the link - https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/perfect-server-ubuntu-with-nginx-and-ispconfig-3/

```
apt-get -y install postfix postfix-mysql postfix-doc mysql-client
mysql-server openssl getmail4 rkhunter binutils dovecot-imapd
dovecot-pop3d dovecot-mysql dovecot-sieve dovecot-lmtpd sudo
```

I am getting the below error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
dovecot-lmtpd : Depends: dovecot-core (= 1:2.2.22-1ubuntu2) but 1:2.2.22-1ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
dovecot-mysql : Depends: dovecot-core (= 1:2.2.22-1ubuntu2) but 1:2.2.22-1ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
```

This the repositries added in my sources list:

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

it is ubuntu 16.04. How I can resolve this.

Comment: Which 16.04 repositories do you have installed? Do you have xenial *and* xenial-updates *and* xenial-security?  What other sources do you have enabled?

Comment: ok update the question.

Comment: Yes this is my first attempt.

Comment: Ugh. Those are awful instructions. Are you really trying to install all those services at once?

Comment: yes. I am installing all at once. But on ubuntu 12.04 there are similar guide and I have followed that and installed it without any issue. This a clients pc, where I am trying to install using SSH.

Comment: First, stop and fix your sources. They are all over the place. Why backports for a server?  Why are repos spattered across so many lines? Do you really need universe and multiverse at all? Without understanding your sources, you're just begging to get pwned.

Comment: it is there in the instructions, that this be added.

Comment: I strongly advise against disabling AppArmor on a machine you're being paid to work on (it's in the instructions, too). Good case for negligence there, unless the client approves disabling Ubuntu's built-in security for their own convenience.

Comment: The short answer to your original question is that you have a version mismatch. Version mismatches are due to either missing sources (like xenial-updates universe, which is missing, or non-Ubuntu software from PPAs and other non-Ubuntu sources. Since you didn't do B, then answer is probably A.

Comment: The easy way to track down version mismatches is using 'apt-cache policy <packagename>' to determine where the latest package is coming from, and 'rmadison <packagename>' to determine the real latest version for that release of Ubuntu.

Comment: thanks it looks like the line you pointed out is there in the instructions, which I have missed. I have updated that. Now checking. will update you.

Comment: Thnaks no error. Now I am able to move on the next screen. please add your suggestion in the answer. so that I can accept your answer.